# virtual directory, accept anything

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, webserver

For my test project I have a directory structure like the following.

```
test/index.php
test/.htaccess
test/style/style.css
test/style/images/test_image.jpg
test/functions/functions.php
```

I want that I can write any URL in the browser, examples:

- localhost/test/fsgdffgs/454-54gfg/fsgdfs545 should point to test/index.php
- localhost/test/fgdsf/fsgdfgsf_ffd/sdgfgdfdfg/ should point to test/index.php
- localhost/test/fjdghjf/jhgjjglh/fkghkgfgkfjgkfjkg should point to test/index.php
- localhost/test/jfdsghjf/index.php should point to test/index.php
- localhost/test/index.php should point to test/index.php
- localhost/test/style/style.css should point to style/style.css
- localhost/test/asfgfgd/hfdgkf/fhdhg/style/style.css should point to style/style.css
- localhost/test/test/style/images/test_image.jpg should point to images/test_image.jpg
- localhost/test/affg/functions/php should point to test/functions/functions.php

**Content of my .htaccess:**

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*\..*)$ $1
```

Somehow it does not work, tried the whole day to write a short config for this. Chrome tells me object not found. **Any idea how I can solve this?** I wrote such a config for my site months ago, but I can't remember...

Comment: please, let us know if the answer solved your question. If so, please mark the question as 'solved', so help you others !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]*)\.css$ /style/$1.css

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]*)\.jpg$ /style/images/$1.jpg

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]*)functions\.php$ /functions/functions.php
```